# unable to execute Python3 in cgi-bin url is executing via python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi-bin

[output in command mode and url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFl1K.png)

**[unable to execute Python3 in cgi-bin url is executing via python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189655/unable-to-execute-python3-in-cgi-bin-url-is-executing-via-python2)**

```
#!/bin/python3.6
# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb, calendar, datetime, time, os, sys
from pyzabbix.api import ZabbixAPI
cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>Zabbix Maintenance</title>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
x = datetime.datetime.now()
yy=x.strftime("%Y")
mm=x.strftime("%m")
dd=x.strftime("%d")
tim=x.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print ('Current date and time of the Zabbix Server is:' + yy + ' ' + mm +' ' + dd +' ' + tim + ' ' +'Please convert maintenance window to Zabbix Server time$
# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
if form.getvalue('first_name'):
        first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
        print ('<h1> Hello ' + first_name + ' thanks for using script... </h1>')
        server_name  = form.getvalue('server_name')
        print ('<h1> The server is ' + server_name + '</h1>')
        Active_Since = form.getvalue('Active_Since')
        s1=Active_Since.split("T")
        s1=s1[0].split("-")
        Y1=int(s1[0])
        m1=int(s1[1])
        d1=int(s1[2])
        s1=Active_Since.split("T")
        s1=s1[1].split(":")
        H1=int(s1[0])
        M1=int(s1[1])
        dt1 = datetime.datetime(Y1,m1,d1,H1,M1)
    a_s=time.mktime(dt1.timetuple())
        #print(a_s)
        a_s=str(a_s)
        print ('<h1> The mm starts from ' + Active_Since + '</h1>')
        active_till = form.getvalue('active_till')
        t2=active_till.split("T")
        t2=t2[0].split("-")
        Y2=int(t2[0])
        m2=int(t2[1])
        d2=int(t2[2])
        t2=active_till.split("T")
        t2=t2[1].split(":")
        H2=int(t2[0])
        M2=int(t2[1])
        dt2 = datetime.datetime(Y2,m2,d2,H2,M2)
        a_t=time.mktime(dt2.timetuple())
        #print(a_t)
        a_t=str(a_t)
```

**i am not able to execute via URL but from commant line a am able execute
both the output is attached in image  **

which python
/bin/python
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
which python3.6
/bin/python3.6

Comment: i need how apache to use python3.x when i hit the URL "http://servername/cgi-bin/4.py"

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the shebang line (the first line) from: `#!/bin/python3` to either `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` or to `#!/bin/python3.6`. I think there's no `python3` executable in your `/bin` directory.

Source: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Run-Python-CGI-from-Apache